# Duvida sobre vetor

Tags: c#, array, for

estou tentando listar os números que o usuário digitar mas não estou encontrando a função,alguém pode me dar uma luz?

```
class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int[] atividade = new int[6];
                for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Insira o " + i + "° numero: ");
                    atividade[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um foreach para fazer isso:

```
int[] atividade = new int[6];
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Insira o " + i + "° numero: ");
    atividade[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
foreach(int i in atividade)
{
    Console.Write($"{i}, ");
}
```

Ele irá percorrer por todos os valores do array e escreve-los na tela.